# Ionic 4 App Crashing on Android 12 After Installation

Tags: ionic-framework

The Ionic app is crashing after installing on Android 12. Need Help

[image]

Comment: Use adb tool to run your app on your phone. This will give you more info what is causing the crash.

Comment: Open project in android studio and check log